# How do I add a UITextView to this UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitextview

I have a `UITableViewCell` that is dynamically sized based on the content in it.  I do this in `heightForRowAtIndexPath` as follows:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  if (indexPath.section == 1 && indexPath.row == 1) {
    NSDictionary *fields = self.messageDetailsDictionary[@"fields"];
    NSString *cellText = fields[@"message_detail"];
    UIFont *cellFont = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0];
    CGSize constraintSize = CGSizeMake(self.tableView.frame.size.width - 50.0f, MAXFLOAT);
    CGSize labelSize = [cellText sizeWithFont:cellFont constrainedToSize:constraintSize lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
    return labelSize.height + 20.0f;
  } else {
    return tableView.rowHeight;
  }
}
```

In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` I customise the cell as follows:

```
case 1:{
  UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell new] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"DetailCell"];
  if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell new] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"DetailCell"];
  }
  NSDictionary *fields = self.messageDetailsDictionary[@"fields"];
  cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
  cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
  cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0];
  cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0; // This means multiline
  cell.textLabel.text = fields[@"message_detail"];
  return cell;
}
```

This all works fine, however I want the content of the cell to detect phone numbers, dates/times etc.  So I think I need to have the content in a `UITextView` within the `UITableViewCell` to make this possible.

How can I dynamically size the `UITextView` and add it to the cell with the content by modifying my code above?  Sample code please with answers because I've already tried adding the UITextView as a subview of the cells contentView but it's not working as I'd expect.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the [`sizeToFit`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/sizeToFit) or [`sizeThatFits:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/sizeThatFits%3a) methods to resize the `UITextView` object

Answer (score 0):

While creating cell, you need to add textView as its subView and no need to set textView size separately. You just need add margin values while returning height for row in

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```